# Java application running as service won't create files

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a simple java application using spring boot that creates files(let's say `/Store/store.txt`) at startup, then uses those files for read and write purpose. Also configured `logging.file=persist/consol-logs/fix-adaptor.log` on `application.properties`.

Now the problem is none of the above files gets created (`/Store/store.txt` or `persist/consol-logs/fix-adaptor.log`).

I am using Maven for the build which gives me an executable jar. Then moving jar on the system (which is test machine running centos). I am running an application(.jar) as a service on centos.

It works fine when I run it on my windows system using `java -jar application.jar`. but it won't work on the test system(centos).

When I run my application on windows (let's say I have my jar on target folder), it creates all directories on target folder but I don't know when I am running it on Linux system where it should create those folder.

What I am doing on Linux system:
1. Created user (Lets say ravi)
`sudo useradd ravi`

2. set password
   `$ sudo passwd ravi@123`
3. Copy `application.jar` to the home directory of user ravi
   then
   `$ sudo chown ravi:ravi /home/ravi/application.jar`
   `$ sudo chmod 500 /home/ravi/application.jar`
4. create symbolic link
   `$ sudo ln -s /home/ravi/application.jar /etc/init.d/my-application`
5. Running application
   `$ sudo service my-application start`

can anyone help to resolve this issue?

The method that creates a directory structure:

```
private boolean createStructure() {
        HashMap<String, String> config = configProvider.getConfig();
        String fileLogPath = config.get("FileLogPath");
        File file = new File(fileLogPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
            LOG.info("### Directories created: " + fileLogPath + " ###");
            return file.exists();
        }
        LOG.info("### Directory creation failed: " + fileLogPath + " ###");
        return file.exists();
    }
```

Where `FileLogPath=fix-adaptor/fix-logs/initiator/`

Comment: Is there any error on Startup?

Comment: it looks like on Centos you (as user) do not have rights to write in `/Store` folder. When you run `java -jar application.jar` what is happening? did you try run this app with spring-boot?

Comment: Are there any errors? Also the service might not have the proper permissions to those files/folders.

Comment: Yes, it showing me `java.io.FileNotFoundException` @MohamedAneesA

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the file on Startup?

Comment: either two folder doesn't exists or not having permission to write into that folder.. Please verify your permission that process have write access on particular folder [`/Store` and `persist/consol-logs`].

Comment: Could you post the entire exception ? Also, you only use `mkdirs()` and you never actually create the file

Comment: Are you sure your application is started? It shouldn't be started using  ` java -jar application.jar`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel ok but in case of logging spring boot should create log file

Comment: @Vasif yes it is, i am running it on command line on windows

Comment: It depends on your spring config. Do you see the log in the console ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Yes

Comment: Then show us the log file with the errors